# How can I set the variable equal to the innerHTML of an element

Tags: javascript

I have a table and I would like to set a variable equal to the innerHTML of a table. I have seen that I can change the innerHTML of an element but I haven't been able to figure out how to see the contents of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tableHtml = document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML;
```

Comment: that does not show nothing. I am trying to get the innerHTML of an unorder list element <ul>

Comment: So sorry. I thought that when you said "I have a table and I would like to set a variable equal to the innerHTML of a table" that you wanted the innerHTML of a table. I am so dumb. I wish I wasn't so dumb!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also:
Html code:

```
Table:<br/>
<table id="tbl" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1.1</td>
        <td>Cell 1.2</td>
        <td>Cell 1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 2.1</td>
        <td>Cell 2.2</td>
        <td>Cell 2.3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
Message:<br/>
<textarea id="message"/>
```

Javascript code:

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
var tblinner = tbl.innerHTML; //save the innerHTML to a variable
var message = document.getElementById('message');
message.value = tblinner; //display the innerHTML value
```

[See it in action from jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/aVAWe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The same way you set it:

```
var tableHTML = document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML;
alert(tableHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(document.getElementById('id_of_the_element').innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought that innerHTML was a set only property and not read. I was having an error about 5 lines above the code that's why I was not being able to see the alert(). sorry about that!